# How to free the memory in child threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory

My main thread has used pthread_create() to created some child threads. In the shut down handler(singal handler for SIGINT and SIGTERM) of the main thread, I want to use pthread_cancel to terminate all other threads. But I have malloc() in the those threads, how to free those memories?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html - is it?

Comment: 'how to free those memories?' - don't bother, don't try.

Answer (score 0):

You must refer http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html

The pthread_kill instruction sends a signal sig to the specified thread. The signal to be sent is specified by sig and is either zero or one of the signals from the list of defined signals in the  header file. If sig is zero, error checking is performed, but no signal is sent to the target thread.

pthread_kill, however, does not kill a thread. If that signal terminates the process, then the whole process ceases, and with it, any dynamically allocated memory by any thread in the process.

There is no way to kill a thread.

Comment: Using the current pthread implementation under Linux is very well possible to kill a specific thread only. @MartinJames However this isn't portable so it's not nice to do so.

Comment: @alk - it's the ONLY way to terminate/kill a thread.  The OS is the only thing that has the tools to do it.  It cannot be done from user code.  pthread lib. just asks the OS to kill it.  User code cannot stop a thread running on another core - that requires inter-core driver action, and only the OS has access to the driver.

Comment: @MartinJames: I fully agree with you. My comment's wording seems to be ambigious... What I wanted to express is: Under Linux the current PThreads implementation allows threads to be killed (by the OS), as threads are implemented as separate processes. So using the result if the `gettid()` system call as parameter to the `kill()` system call allows it to end one specific thread a process' (**without** ending the whole process (and with this all other possible threads of this process)).